# how to do exception in Jtextfield?

Tags: exception, jtextfield

i am trying to get the work on this code i would like to know how can i will be able to catch exceptions in Jtextfield and i would also like to limit the amount that you can put in the Jtextfield. Plz let me know how can i do that i tried different things but nothing work and also i create this program on Netbeans using desktop application. here is the code

```
private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                







          double price1 = (int) ((int) Double.parseDouble(carpetPricetxt.getText()));
          boolean incorrect = true;
          while (incorrect){
          try{Double.parseDouble(price1);incorrect = false;}
          catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
           price1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid input");




          }
          int carpetSize = (int) ((int) Double.parseDouble( CarpetLengthtxt.getText()));



          double room= 0;
          double carptCst= (price1/9)*carpetSize;
          double labrCst= 90;
          double subTotal = (price1/9)*carpetSize+labrCst;
          String tax1 ="0.5%"; 
          double totl= (price1/9)*carpetSize+labrCst+.5*subTotal;
          double fruniture=0;

          String zero = "0";
          String one= "1";
          String two= "2";
          String three= "3";
          String four= "4";
          String five= "5";
          String six= "6";
          String seven= "7";
          String eight= "8";
          String nine= "9";
          String ten= "10";
          Object str= roomCountComboBox.getSelectedItem();
          if (roomCountComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(zero))
          {
              room= totl;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(room));
          }
          if (roomCountComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(one))
          {
              room= totl*1;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(room));
          }
          if (roomCountComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(two))
          {
              room= totl*2;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(room));
          }
          if (roomCountComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(three))
          {
              room= totl*3;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(room));
          }
          if (roomCountComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(four))
          {
              room= totl*4;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(room));
          }
          if (roomCountComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(five))
          {
              room= totl*5;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(room));
          }
          if (roomCountComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(six))
          {
              room= totl*6;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(room));
          }
          if (roomCountComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(seven))
          {
              room= totl*7;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(room));
          }
          if (roomCountComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(eight))
          {
              room= totl*8;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(room));
          }
          if (roomCountComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(nine))
          {
              room= totl*9;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(room));
          }
          if (roomCountComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(ten))
          {
              room= totl*10;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(room));
          }



          Object str2= furnitureComboBox.getSelectedItem();
          if (furnitureComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(zero))
          {
              fruniture=room+totl;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(fruniture));
          }
          if (furnitureComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(one))
          {
                fruniture=room+totl*1;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(fruniture));
          }
          if (furnitureComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(two))
          {
                fruniture=room+totl*2;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(fruniture));
          }
          if (furnitureComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(three))
          {
              fruniture=room+totl*3;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(fruniture));
          }
          if (furnitureComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(four))
          {
              fruniture=room+totl*4;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(fruniture));
          }
          if (furnitureComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(five))
          {
              fruniture=room+totl*5;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(fruniture));
          }
          if (furnitureComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(six))
          {
              fruniture=room+totl*6;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(fruniture));
          }
          if (furnitureComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(seven))
          {
              fruniture=room+totl*7;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(fruniture));
          }
          if (furnitureComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(eight))
          {
              fruniture=room+totl*8;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(fruniture));
          }
          if (furnitureComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(nine))
          {
              fruniture=room+totl*9;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(fruniture));
          }
          if (furnitureComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(ten))
          {
              fruniture=room+totl*10;
              grandTotalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(fruniture));
          }




         TaxLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(tax1));
         laborCostLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(labrCst));
         carpetCostLable2.setText(String.valueOf(carptCst));
         totalLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(subTotal));


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what, exactly, you're asking. If you tighten up your question a bit, I might be able to provide more specific help. But I think this part of the [official Java tutorial on textfields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) is relevant:

> Because the `JTextField` class inherits from the `JTextComponent` class, text fields are very flexible and can be customized almost any way you like. For example, you can add a document listener or a document filter to be notified when the text changes, and **in the filter case you can modify the text field accordingly**.

(emphasis mine)

---

As a sidenote, this:

```
  Object str2= furnitureComboBox.getSelectedItem();
  if (furnitureComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(zero))
  {
      fruniture=room+totl;
  ...
```

would be a bit better-written as this:

```
Object selectedFurniture = furnitureComboBox.getSelectedItem();
if(selectedFurniture.equals(zero))
{
    furniture = room + total;
...
```

Note the improved spelling ("fruniture" is not a word), slightly-improved nomenclature, and more concise predicate in the `if`.